Styling NavigationLink like a button
I have the following code to style a NavigationLink:
 NavigationLink("Red") {
                ColorDetail(color: .red)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .tint(.white)
            .cornerRadius(5)

Only the text is clickable. How do I make it so that the colored background is also clickable (it looks like a button and I want the whole surface of the button to be clickable, not just the text).

Try applying the styling via a ButtonStyle, see How to style a view when used as a NavigationLink
